# Determining exact value of $\cos (A+B)$ in a specific quadrant

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The question reads:

Angles $A$ and $B$ are obtuse angles in quadrant 2 (II). If $\csc A = 3$ and $\tan B$ = -1/3, determine the exact value of $\cos (A+B)$.

How would I take on this question? Generally when I am given $\cos (A+B)$, the two values to insert into the expanded formula are given.

Comment: Well, since they are not given, perhaps the problem (or the book or the teacher) expects you to *compute* them from the values that *were* given? For example, if $\csc A = 3$, then what is $\sin A$? How about $\cos A$?

Comment: The sum-to-products formula for $\cos(A+B)$ is handy here.

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the sum of angles formula 
$$\cos(A + B) = \cos A\cos B - \sin A\sin B$$
we must determine $\cos A$, $\sin A$, $\cos B$, $\sin B$.

Here are two approaches.

**Method 1:**  Use trigonometric identities.

We are given a second-quadrant angle $A$ with $\csc A = 3$.  By definition, 
$$\csc A = \frac{1}{\sin A}$$
Solving for $\sin A$ yields
$$\sin A = \frac{1}{\csc A}$$
Substitute $3$ for $\csc A$ to find $\sin A$.

Next, use the Pythagorean Identity $\sin^2A + \cos^2A = 1$.  Solving for $\cos^2A$ yields 
$$\cos^2A = 1 - \sin^2A$$
Since $A$ is a second-quadrant angle, $\cos A < 0$.  Thus, we take the negative square root, so 
$$\cos A = -\sqrt{1 - \sin^2A}$$

We are given a second-quadrant angle $B$ with $\tan B = -1/3$.  We can determine $\sec^2B$ using the trigonometric identity
$$\tan^2B + 1 = \sec^2B$$
Since $B$ is a second-quadrant angle, $\sec B < 0$.  Thus, 
$$\sec B = -\sqrt{\tan^2B + 1}$$
Substitute $-1/3$ for $\tan B$ to find $\sec B$.

By definition, 
$$\sec B = \frac{1}{\cos B}$$
Solving for $\cos B$ yields 
$$\cos B = \frac{1}{\sec B}$$
To find $\sin B$, use the Pythagorean identity $\sin^2B + \cos^2B = 1$.  Solving for $\sin^2B$ yields
$$\sin^2B = 1 - \cos^2B$$
Since $B$ is a second-quadrant angle, $\sin B > 0$.  Thus, we take the non-negative square root, which yields
$$\sin B = \sqrt{1 - \cos^2B}$$

**Method 2:**  Draw a diagram.

Since angle $A$ is a second-quadrant angle with $\csc A = 3$, we draw a right triangle in the second quadrant with hypotenuse $3$, opposite side $1$, and adjacent side $|x|$ such that the terminal side of the angle passes through the point $(x, 1)$.  The value of $|x|$ can be determined with the Pythagorean Theorem.  Observe that $x < 0$ in the second-quadrant.

Since angle $B$ is a second-quadrant angle with $\tan B = -1/3$, we draw a right triangle in the second quadrant with opposite side $1$, adjacent side $3$, and hypotenuse $r$ such that the terminal side of the angle passes through the point $(-3, 1)$.  The value of $r$ can be determined with the Pythagorean Theorem.

[image: triangles_for_second-quadrant_angles]

To determine $\cos A$, $\sin A$, $\cos B$, $\sin B$, use the definitions 
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta & = \frac{x}{r}\\
\sin\theta & = \frac{y}{r}
\end{align*}
where $(x, y)$ is a point on the terminal side of angle $\theta$ that is $r$ units from the origin.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try and walk you through the problem.

First re-write $\text{csc }A = 3$ as $\frac{1}{\text{sin } A} = 3$. After a little re-arranging we have that $\text{sin }A = \frac{1}{3}$. Next, use a right triangle (recall that sin x = $\frac{opp}{hyp}$) and pythagoras theorem to solve for the missing side. This is how you can get $\text{cos } A$ (recall that cos x = $\frac{adj}{hyp}$)

Now temporarily ignore the fact that $\text{tan } B$ is negative and assume that $\text{tan } B = \frac{1}{3}$. Do the same thing you did above to fill out the appropriate right triangle with all the side lengths filled in. You can get $\text{sin } B$ and $\text{cos } B$ here.

And finally, just use the known trig identity $\text{cos }(A + B) = \text{cos}(A)\text{cos}(B) - \text{sin}(A)\text{sin}(B)$

Making sure to choose the angles $A$ and $B$ that reside in the second quadrant